# What are the requirements to enter Prifddinas?

Tags: runescape

I've heard that the city in RuneScape will be for high-levelled players only. But I can't find the exact requirements needed to enter the city. What are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enter Prifddinas(Elf City), there is only the quest requirement of finishing Plague's End.  Plague's End does have requirements in order to start it.

Quest requirements:

```
- Making History
    - The Restless Ghost
    - Priest in Peril
- Catapult Construction
- Within the Light
    - Mourning's Ends Part II
        - Mourning's Ends Part I
            - Big Chompy Bird Hunting
            - Sheep Herder
            - Roving Elves
                - Waterfall Quest
                - Regicide
                    - Underground Pass
                        - Biohazard
                            - Plague City
```

The level requirements for Plague's End are:

```
75 Construction
75 Dungeoneering
75 Agility
75 Crafting
75 Herblore
75 Mining
75 Prayer
75 Summoning
```

Once you have finished Plague's End you will have access to Prifddinas!  Just head to the gates in Tirannwn, and enjoy the beautiful city.

[Plague's End Wiki Source](https://runescape.wiki/w/Plague%27s_End)

Comment: thankyou soooo much for the information! only issue i had was when you said the quests was in order i assumed they started from the top ( making history being the first to do and etc just realised i have to start plagues end first! please update it for dummys like me :D other than that prif here i come!

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete Plague's end quest, which requires Within the light quest, Making history quest, Catapult construction quest and level 75 in 8 skills.

EDIT: The skills are construction, agility, crafting, herblore, mining, prayer and summoning

Comment: Which skills ? Any source on what you're saying ?

Comment: 8 any skills. http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Prifddinas http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Plague%27s_End

Comment: Sorry it was level 75 in Construction, dungeoneering, agility, crafting, herblore, mining, prayer and summoning

Answer (score 1):

You need to have these 10 skills up to level 75 :

- Mining
- Summoning
- Herblore
- Agility
- Construction
- Dungeoneering
- Prayer
- Crafting
- **Ranged**
- **Woodcutting**

Plus the masses of quests that were already mentionned.
It may say different on the WIKI page but in Runescape if you check the Quest Journal for Plagues end it tells you, you need ranged and woodcutting as well.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know you could do dot points, thank you Anton for fixing it up to make it sound less arrogant

Answer (score 0):

On top of the listed requirements that people have already mentioned, you also need 
**70 Fletching** as it is one of the requirements in the Within the Light quest - a pre-requisite for Plague's End.
https://runescape.wiki/w/Within_the_Light